# Mousedown event handler interferes with key handlers

Tags: javascript, dom-events

My application kept misbehaving. After removing more and more code I managed to find the core of the problem which however makes no sense to me.

Bit of a background. My web editor application reacts to key strokes, e.g. when <kbd>Alt</kbd> is pressed, handlers for resizing are hidden. It also reacts to mouse operations for dragging, resizing, deleting, drawing a selection box, etc. When experimenting with event handlers and preventing default behavior (I didn't want <kbd>Alt</kbd> to change focus to browser menu, neither mouse to select text), I found a weird thing.

When I create event handlers for `keyup` and `keydown` (and these contain `preventDefault()`), it works fine. However when I add handler for `mousedown`, it works as well, but the previous handlers stop working. If I remove `preventDefault()` from the `mousedown` handler, all works fine.

Here's my JS code stripped to minimum (or rather created for purposes of verifying the problem is not somewhere else):

```
// it works fine with these events
var events = ['keyup', 'keydown'];

// but when mousedown is added, its preventDefault() method somehow breaks keydown and keyup
//var events = ['keyup', 'keydown', 'mousedown'];

var log = document.getElementById('log');

var handler = function(e) {
  log.innerHTML = e.type + '<br>' + log.innerHTML;
  e.preventDefault();
}

for (var i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
  window.addEventListener(events[i], handler);
}
```

See jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/76x8B/1/).

Why on earth would `preventDefault()` method in `mousedown` handler interfere with key events?

Tested in Chrome and Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

**New:**

I just had to test it further and further. It seems that `this.focus()` works as well as `documen.getElementById().focus()` and `window.focus()` from my last update. Best practice (IMO) will be using `this` because it's universal reference to clicked object.

**Latest old:** [New Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/76x8B/6/)

Finaly! What I did wrong was using `document` object while I should use `window`. This time there's no errors in console in any tested browser (even IE11). So the code should look like this:

```
var handler = function(e) {
    log.innerHTML = e.type + '<br>' + log.innerHTML;
    document.focus();
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

**Old 2:** I just tested this further this time. It seems that `e.preventDefault()` on `mousedown` doesn't break other events and is working just as it should: prevents default action which is (among the others) setting `focus` on the DOM element. I tried same code on local html file and it works perfectly. What you need to do is to set focus by yourself on object that has to read those events.

**EDIT:** [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/silveraven/76x8B/4/) and code of `handler` function:

```
var handler = function(e) {
    log.innerHTML = e.type + '<br>' + log.innerHTML;
    document.focus();
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

**Old 1:** That's because `mousedown` event lasts until you 'let it go' (try same code but use `mouseup` instead of `mousedown`). It just doesn't work like `keydown` where event is being sent, ends and then this event is repeated until you stop pressing the key.

Comment: Which doesn't explain why `mousedown` prevents key handlers from working, neither helps me to solve the issue with `mousedown`. Btw, I was NOT complaining that `mousedown` is sent once, while `keydown` is sent repeatedly.

Comment: After longer an more detailed testing: Updated answer with better explanation.

Comment: OK, initially I thought you made it, but after looking at it a bit longer, all you just did was adding a call to undefined (`document.focus === undefined`), which throws exception (check console) and prevents `e.preventDefault()` from being called. Which obviously didn't solve the problem. I was too quick with upvoting :)

Comment: Well... My console is blank. Completely. Both on Chrome and Firefox. Here's where I found solution: [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_html_focus.asp). And I'm sure focusing on element is the problem 'cause simple page with that code (even without `document.focus()`) works perfectly.

Comment: Oh... I was able to recreate that issue. I'll try solve it properly.

Comment: Cool! Please update the code (answers should not rely on jsFiddle link) and if possible, add some reasoning, why now it works. At least for me setting focus to window doesn't make any sense at all :)

Comment: @Enethion why did you set focus on window object?